# Python: Appending to a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm working on a definition tester (you enter in words, their part of speeches, and synonyms for each, and it tests you on them). Problem I have is with the part that gets the word:

```
   def get_word(): # this is in another function, that's why it is indented
      import easygui as eg
      word_info = eg.multenterbox(msg = 'Enter in the following information about each word.'
                                , title = 'Definition Tester'
                                , fields = ['Word: ', 'Part of Speech: ', 'Synonyms (separated by spaces): ']
                                , values = []
                                )
      return word_info
   for i in range(n):
      my_list = get_word()
      print my_list # for testing
      word, pOS, synonyms = my_list[0], my_list[1], my_list[2]
      word = word.capitalize()
      synonyms = synonyms.split(', ')
      words_list += word
      print word # for testing
      test_dict[word] = [pOS, synonyms]
   print words_list # for testing
```

However, `words_list` ends up being the word(s) after the `list(word)` function is applied to them--- I'm not sure why.

For example: if the only word was 'word', `words_list` turns out to be `['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']`. If there were two words ('dog', 'cat'), `words_list` turns out to be `['d', 'o', 'g', 'c', 'a', 't']`.
Here is my input (into `get_word()`): Word: 'myword', Part of Speech: 'n', Synonyms: 'synonym, definition'.

This is the output I get:

```
['myword', 'n', 'synonym, definition']
Myword
['M', 'y', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd'] # Why does this happen?
```

This is the only thing wrong with my program... If I could get some input on how to fix this and what is wrong, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you print `word_info`?

Comment: `my_list` is equal to `word_info`, as the function `get_word()` is returning `word_info`, and `my_list` is set to whatever it returns (`my_list = get_word()`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
words_list += word
```

`+=` on a list is for adding *all the elements in another list*.  As it happens, Python strings also function like lists of characters, so you are adding each character to the list as its own element.

You want this:

```
words_list.append(word)
```

which is for adding a single element to the end.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with it, I figured out the problem myself, so I thought I should put it here for anyone who has something similar:

Instead of doing `words_list += word`, it should be: `words_list.append(word)`.

Or, which is what I did, you can do: `words_list += [word]`. Now, `word` is a `list` object, so it will add onto the previous list.

Comment: `words_list += [word]` isn't very Pythonic. `.append()` exists for a reason. You should accept Eevee's answer.

Comment: But it works. Regardless of whether it is Pythonic or not, it does the job effectively, and does not take a significant difference in memory nor computational speed between `list += [element]` or `list.append(element)`.